# Write a SELECT statement that returns these columns from the db1.MyGuitarShop.Products table:

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

1. The `ListPrice` column
2. A column that uses the `CAST` function to return the `ListPrice` column with 1 digit to the right of the decimal point
3. A column that uses the `CONVERT` function to return the `ListPrice` column as an integer
4. A column that uses the `CAST` function to return the `ListPrice` column as an integer

I started it like this but as you can see this is wrong because I didn't use `CAST` or `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT ProductName, ListPrice, DateAdded
FROM MyGuitarShop.Products
WHERE ListPrice > 500 AND ListPrice < 2000
ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
```

Can anybody help me with the syntax?

Comment: You can select 'created' columns as result of such functions. eg SELECT CAST(ListPrice) as newColumn

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
SELECT
    ListPrice,
    CAST(ListPrice AS decimal(10, 1)) AS ListPriceCast,
    CONVERT(decimal(10, 1), ListPrice) AS ListPriceConvert,
    CAST(ListPrice AS int) AS ListPriceInteger
FROM MyGuitarShop.Products;
```

To obtain the list price as a number with one decimal place of precision, we can cast/convert to `decimal(10, 1)`, which means a number with 10 total digits of precision, one of which is to the right of the decimal point.